# how to condition every 3 times data is echoed i will change to another div and every 6 times data echoed it will change to another div again

Tags: javascript, php, html, echo

I dont know how to explained it detailly, but this is my html code.

```
 <div class="w3-content w3-display-container  mySlides">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <img src="Image/2.jpg" class="gbr"/>
                        <span>Rp.5000 / ikat </span><button class="tengbr">Beli</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <img src="Image/3.jpg" class="gbr"/>
                        <span>Rp.9000 / ikat </span><button class="tengbr">Beli</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <img src="Image/2.jpg" class="gbr"/>
                        <span>Rp.8000 / ikat </span><button class="tengbr">Beli</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <img src="Image/3.jpg" class="gbr"/>
                        <span>Rp.8000 / ikat </span><button class="tengbr">Beli</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <img src="Image/2.jpg" class="gbr"/>
                        <span>Rp.8000 / ikat </span><button class="tengbr">Beli</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 akhir">
                        <img src="Image/3.jpg" class="gbr"/>
                        <span>Rp.9000 / ikat </span><button class="tengbr">Beli</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-content w3-display-container  mySlides">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <img src="Image/2.jpg" class="gbr"/>
                        <span>Rp.5000 / ikat </span><button class="tengbr">Beli</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <img src="Image/2.jpg" class="gbr"/>
                        <span>Rp.9000 / ikat </span><button class="tengbr">Beli</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <img src="Image/3.jpg" class="gbr"/>
                        <span>Rp.8000 / ikat </span><button class="tengbr">Beli</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <img src="Image/3.jpg" class="gbr"/>
                        <span>Rp.8000 / ikat </span><button class="tengbr">Beli</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <img src="Image/2.jpg" class="gbr"/>
                        <span>Rp.8000 / ikat </span><button class="tengbr">Beli</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 akhir">
                        <img src="Image/2.jpg" class="gbr"/>
                        <span>Rp.9000 / ikat </span><button class="tengbr">Beli</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

this is actually only the html code, the real php code is only echo the imgsrc,span's and button's innertext from databases, but as you see, every 3 time's data echoed it must be add another `<div class="row">`
and every 6 data echoed it have to add `<div class="w3-content w3-display-container  mySlides">`
i use this php code to show my data

```
$sql = "select * from tbproduk where namaproduk LIKE '$produk%' ";
                $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die("error $sql");
                $num = mysqli_num_rows($query);
                $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
                for($x = 1;$x<=$num;$x++){
                    $namaproduk = $result['namaproduk'];
                    $harga = $result['harga'];
                    //etc.. just put the data in variabel and then echo in html
                }
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might just work...

```
for($x = 1;$x<=$num/3;$x++){ 
echo '<div class="w3-content w3-display-container  mySlides">
  <div class="row">';
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
         echo'<div class="col-4">
                        <img src="YOUR_SRC" class="gbr"/>
                        <span>YOUR_SPAN </span><button class="tengbr">YOUR_BUTTON</button>
                    </div>';
                }
      echo'</div>
            </div>';
}
```

Comment: it actually work but not perfect yet, my data only shown if my total data can be divided by 3